# Sharepoint Foundation 2010: hide ribbon completely

Tags: sharepoint, ribbon, sharepointfoundation2010

I am trying to style the master page in Sharepoint Foundation 2010. I"m using the nightandday master and styles.

The design has no ribbon and I just need to turn it off. Just plain old off. When I set the ribbon div to display: none, the entire top banner disappears.

I'm not a sharepoint dev and am lost in general. Is there an easy way to just hide/get rid of the ribbon? Nothing fancy about permissions required--just needs to be always gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the information in this article to get you started.

http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2010/11/09/hiding-the-sharepoint-2010-ribbon-from-anonymous-users/

Comment: This brings up a good point - you do not want to hide the ribbon for all users. If you do, you've effectively created a read-only (or at best, an add-only) web site.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully this will work. I don't have a way to test it but when I add it to the master page, Sharepoint doesn't complain!

Answer (score 3):

The CSS classes you want to look at are;

```
<style type="text/css">
    div#s4-ribbonrow.s4-pr.s4-ribbonrowhidetitle { height:43px !important }
    /*.ms-cui-ribbon { display:none; }*/
    .s4-ribbonrowhidetitle s4-notdlg noindex { height: 43px !important; }
    .s4-title h1 a,.s4-title h2 a,.s4-title h2 { font-size: small; }
    .ms-pagetitleareaframe table { background: none; }
    #s4-leftpanel-content { display:none !important; }
    #s4-titlerowhidetitle { display:none !important; }
    .s4-ca { margin-left:0px !important; margin-right:0px !important; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone has been struggling with this issue. Hiding the Ribbon may cause some further issues (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9422aa0f-5010-4691-a0ab-25e7aca6b478/issue-with-div-s4workspace-and-scroll-bar)

Especially if you will include your own header and hide the Ribbon.

A quick workaround is using css. #s4-workspace will still receive the correct height & scrollbar won't be an issue as well as the ribbon will be hidden.:

```
body #s4-ribbonrow {
    height: 0px !important;
    min-height: 0px !important;
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

As documented in the linked page of knight0323's answer, the ribbon can be hidden by editing `v4.master` and wrapping the ribbon div with `<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl/>`:

```
<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl PermissionsString="ManagePermissions" runat="server">
    <div id="s4-ribbonrow" class="s4-pr s4-ribbonrowhidetitle">
        <!-- Ribbon code appears here... -->
    </div>
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

Unfortunately on my system this has a side-effect where the page's scroll-bar starts misbehaving. This appears to be a result of a dependency between the ribbon and the `s4-workspace` div. So to resolve this I moved `<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl/>` in from the ribbon div to wrap the `<div id="s4-ribboncont">` and added the following markup near the top of `v4.master`:

```
<style type="text/css">
        #s4-ribbonrow { display: none; }
</style>
<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl PermissionsString="ManagePermissions" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
        #s4-ribbonrow { display: block; }
    </style>
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

The effect of this is that the ribbon is hidden by default but sufficient markup remains in the DOM so the page continues to behave correctly. For administrators, the ribbon is displayed normally.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody else is struggling with this,  here are full instructions to do this without breaking the scroll bar or losing the title bar area, or any other oddities:

[Hiding a Sharepoint 2010 ribbon that does not lose the titlebar area](http://the-simple-programmer.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/hiding-sharepoint-2010-ribbon-from.html)